# Rendering/DeSerializing an http request

Tags: c#, httprequest

I am new to C# and don't know how rendering of a http request works. I was trying to understand a piece of code which I have shared below but didn't understand what's happening in it. It would be helpful if someone can help what the code is trying to do and if there is a way of doing this in a much more efficient way rather than writing 50 lines of code.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(4096);
List<string> results = new List<string>();

while (true)
{
   // Request is http request
   var bytesRemaining = await this.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, offset: 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);

   if (bytesRemaining == 0)
   {
       results.Add(builder.ToString());
       break;
   }

   // Instead of adding the entire buffer into the StringBuilder
   // only add the remainder after the last \n in the array.
   var prevIndex = 0;
   int index;
   while (true)
   {
       index = Array.IndexOf(buffer, (byte)'\n', prevIndex);
       if (index == -1)
       {
           break;
       }
       var encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, prevIndex, index - prevIndex);
       if (builder.Length > 0)
       {
           // If there was a remainder in the string buffer, include it in the next string.
           results.Add(builder.Append(encodedString).ToString());
           builder.Clear();
       }
       else
       {
           results.Add(encodedString);
       }
       // Skip past last \n
       prevIndex = index + 1;
   }

   var remainingString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, prevIndex, bytesRemaining - prevIndex);
   builder.Append(remainingString);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? If you have a JSON encoded string in the body of the request, it can be deserialized as a parameter on the endpoint itself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. If possible, add a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.